# Development kit for Bluetooth which allows customisation of the modulation algorithms

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, signal-processing, software-defined-radio

We need to perform some experiments on the Bluetooth protocol, and for this we need a development kit which allows us to implement/modify different parts of the [Bluetooth protocol stack](http://cnss.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/bt1.jpg).

We have been looking at the TI MSP430 Wireless Development Tool ([EZ430-RF2500](http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/ez430-rf2500.html)).
This kit contains a MSP430 MCU and a CC2500 multi-channel RF transceiver.

The CC2500 is able to perform GFSK modulation, and thus this kit allows us to implement everything from about half of the Baseband block, the Link Manager, the Logical Link Control Adaptation Protocol and so forth in software. And therefore allows us to do the modifications and experiments we want.

However, we also need to have the ability to customise the actual modulation algorithm, as this is a important part in the experiments. The CC2500 does not allow this.

**Which development kit allows us to implement (part of) the Bluetooth protocol stack including the modulation algorithms in software?**

It is also important that it is a development kit, and not just a couple of ICs that may be used in combination for the purpose.

My guess is that we need some kind of software defined radio kit containing a simple RF 2.4GHz front-end connected with a programmable DSP which performs the actual modulation. I have unfortunately not been able to find such a kit.

I really hope someone out there has an idea for just the right solution. Thanks. ;)

**Update:**

I have looked at the GNURadio + USRP + 2.4GHz daughterboard solution. The problem is that there is simply way too big a delay from sampling on the USRP, transferring it via. USB to a computer, demodulation, decoding and interpreting the protocol, to synthesising an answer, transferring it over USB and transmitting it in the air, to implement any protocol like Bluetooth. I know this because I have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the GNU Radio (gnuradio.org) SDR toolkit. Several projects (such as [this one](http://www.usenix.org/event/woot07/tech/full_papers/spill/spill_html/)) have successfully used it for Bluetooth research.

There also exists development hardware designed for use with GNU Radio called the Universal Software Radio Peripheral which, with a suitable daughterboard for 2.4GHz development, costs around $1000.

Comment: Thanks. See the updated question. The link you provide is for a project which only listened on Bluetooth communication between other devices, it never actually communicated with other Bluetooth devices. If you know other projects that actually do that, I would be very interested.

The GNURadio + USRP solution simply has too large a delay to be useable for something like Bluetooth.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you mean by USRP having too large a delay and how you concluded that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are only a few [good solutions](http://www.lyrtech.com/index.php?act=view&pv=SFF%20SDR%20development%20platforms) out there which are really expensive. The USRP might be usable for packet radio with the addition of the "experimental feature" of in-band signalling, but there will still be a significant delay between reception and a transmission based on that reception.